# Should you use error handling even if your program is static?

Tags: python, error-handling

When designing an application that is static, where no input is coming from outside the program, is it worth while to have error handling even when using a language like python that doesn't need to be compiled?

Is it just a best practice?

I use python as an example because of its duck-typing nature.

Comment: Yeah, probably. Being compiled doesn't seem to have much to do with it...?

Comment: Neither does whether or not it gets input from the outside.

Comment: Wouldn't the process of compiling catch errors, like type errors. while python would just silently convert the type?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I believe outside input does matter, but I suppose that's more error handling rather than test cases, in context of the question.

Comment: @DrewAckerman Python is a strongly-typed language. It will not silently convert types (a few exceptions e.g. `int` and `float` types with arithmetic, for closely related types notwithstanding). Try to do `1 + "2"` in the interpreter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, it is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @DrewAckerman Yes, it is dynamically typed, and yet, it is still strongly typed. An example of a weakly-typed language is Perl. The opposite of dynamically typed is not *strongly* typed but *statically* typed.

Comment: @juanoa.arrivillaga well thank you for teaching me that, very important :) Also what do you think about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, unit testing is to test your own program's logic. If you have a program with functions doing different tasks agnostic to data coming from a user or another function it should be tested. The two points you bring up on if it should be tested or not doesn't affect unit testability.

Comment: Ah, so I should be talking about error handling, not unit testing.

Comment: The tag of the question had unit-testing and testing was mentioned in the question so I answered for that.

Comment: You're answer helped me realize I was talking about the wrong thing, thank you.